# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed. Rjindaal encryption

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, encryption, cryptography

I am using same initialization vector and same key for encryption and decryption. However I am getting error saying "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" In web application I am encrypting data and saving encrypted data inside sql server table column (nvarchar(max)). I have windows service which reads encrypted data and decrypt. Can someone please tell me where am I doing wrong.

```
public byte[] Encrypt(string clearText, string key, byte[] initialisationVector, int blockSizeInBits)
{//hidden logic
    rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    rijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
//hidden logic
        return memoryStream.ToArray();

    }
```

calling like this

```
    Dim encryptionKey As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Key")
    ' Arrange - need 32 byte IV for 256-bit
    Dim cryptographer3 As ICryptographer = New Cryptographer()
    Dim initialisationVector3 As Byte() = {&H26, &HDC, &HFF, &H0, &HAD, &HED, _
        &H7A, &HEE, &HC5, &HFE, &H7, &HAF, _
        &H4D, &H8, &H22, &H3C, &H26, &HDC, _
        &HFF, &H0, &HAD, &HED, &H7A, &HEE, _
        &HC5, &HFE, &H7, &HAF, &H4D, &H8, _
        &H22, &H3C}

    ' Act
    Dim encryptedString As Byte() = cryptographer3.Encrypt(strForEncryption, encryptionKey, initialisationVector3, 256)
    'Dim decrypt3 As String = cryptographer3.Decrypt(encryptedString, Key, initialisationVector3, 256)
    Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(encryptedString)
```

decryption method

```
public string Decrypt(byte[] cipherText, string key, byte[] initialisationVector, int blockSizeInBits)
{
  //hidden logic
    rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    rijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    //hidden logic
}
```

callling like this

```
if (encryptedIdentificationValue.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            string decryptionKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"];
            // Arrange - need 32 byte IV for 256-bit
            ICryptographer cryptographer3 = new Cryptographer();
            byte[] initialisationVector3 =
                {
                    0x26, 0xdc, 0xff, 0x0, 0xad, 0xed,
                    0x7a, 0xee, 0xc5, 0xfe, 0x7, 0xaf,
                    0x4d, 0x8, 0x22, 0x3c, 0x26, 0xdc,
                    0xff, 0x0, 0xad, 0xed, 0x7a, 0xee,
                    0xc5, 0xfe, 0x7, 0xaf, 0x4d, 0x8,
                    0x22, 0x3c
                };

            return cryptographer3.Decrypt(encryptedIdentificationValue, decryptionKey, initialisationVector3, 256);
        }
```

Comment: Rijndael with 256-bit blocks – interesting choice. It's not well supported outside .NET and perhaps PHP. I wonder what's behind the choice?

Comment: Its a project requirement to use 256bit encryption

Comment: You seem to have essentially left out all the code that is actually likely to contain the bug - there's probably something wrong in the `Encrypt` function, the `Decrypt` function or when writing data to/reading data from the database (or some combination thereof) and yet have given no relevant code for any of these methods.

Comment: @AshifNataliya you seem to be confusing block size with key size. Standard AES always uses a 128-bit block (and IV) even if you are using a 256-bit key. Rijndael does support a tweakable blocksize but was removed before it was standardized as AES. There is very little support for a 256-bit block.

Answer (score 1):

The "Padding is invalid" message can mean many different things.  It might be a problem with just the padding, or it might be a problem with the whole encryption including the padding.  You can take some steps to diagnose the problem.

1. Set the decryption method to expect no padding.
2. Decrypt a message.  You will not get the padding error, since you
   aren't checking it.
3. Look at the decrypted message.  If it is junk all the way through,
   then your problem is not padding but either encryption or
   decryption, usually decryption.  Check that your key and IV are
   byte for byte the same.  If the message is fine, with some extra
   characters at the end, then check that those extra characters match
   what you would expect from [PKCS7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#PKCS7) padding.
4. When you have diagnosed the problem, you *must* set the decryption
   method back to PKCS7 padding.